# jQuery: Prepend HTML without moving position

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

Let's say, I have a long list of messages, which automatically updates. As for now, I have there a small button that asks the user to refresh, because I don't want to prepend those messages while the user is reading - thus disturbing his read flow.

My other idea was to prepend the data, but rather than pushing the whole document down, I would like it to push the top up, so the new messages are inserted without changing the users reading position (except they're at the very top).

How can this be achieved? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Pe6a8/2/

Pretty sure that is what you wanted. Do I deserve a cookie? :3

Comment: Indeed you do. You can find it on your browser. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way I could think of is to prepend the new html div's with display:none attribute. When the user scrolls up we can then change the display attribute to show him the new html div's.